# Emacs minibuffer typing backwards while debugging

Tags: emacs, elisp

Frequently when debugging backtraces pop up in Emacs, the minibuffer stops working properly. Specifically, anything I try typing in it 'types backward'. See the following screenshot (I was trying to type 'haskell' in the minibuffer):

[image: typing backward]

When I quit out of the debug pane, the minibuffer starts typing normally again.

What's causing this? Any suggestions on how I can make it stop?

Comment: Do you set `bidi-display-reordering` or `bidi-paragraph-direction` anywhere? Is there maybe a unicode rlm somewhere?

Comment: Not manually. `bidi-display-reordering` seems to be set to `t` regardless of whether the minibuffer is typing backwards or not, and `bidi-paragraph-direction` is always set to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

As nmichaels says, this is possibly related to the bidi-display-reordering setting (which is true by default, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Bidirectional-Editing.html

Could it be that the abbrev-insert or any other part of your code inserts one of the Unicode characters that change the direction of your text?

Comment: As I said to nmichaels, the bidi settings don't change - they're set to defaults always.

And now that you mention the abbrev-insert command above, that sounds like it could be a likely culprit. It's part of the `haskell-mode`plugin I set up recently. Since I haven't heard anyone else complain about the same issue, I'm assuming it must be a relatively isolated issue. Do you have any clue what might be going on?

Comment: To be honest, no, I don't really know. But I have experienced issues in programs other than Emacs where a non-printing character causes the flow of text to change around.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this is that something makes it so that after inserting a character, Emacs moves point back to before that character.  Why?  I'm not completely sure, but I have a hunch:

Emacs is very smart, so it probably noticed you're coding in a pure language and figures you probably don't want to change "point" with those nasty side effects, so it resets it back to its initial value for you.